# Translatin string on one sheet to numbers on another sheet in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to create a loop to translate project rankings on sheet1 (low, medium, high, extreme..) to umber values on sheet 3 so that I can rank them.

I am currently linking sheet3 to sheet1 to translate the values by
`=IF(Sheet1!B2 = "low",1,IF(Sheet1!B2="medium",2,IF(Sheet1!B2="high",2,...)`

I would like to do this in a loop so I can have it translate all the values on sheet1 to sheet3 on the press of a button.  My values range from column B row 2 to column F and I want it to do it for every entry even if i add more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you entered the formula in Sheet3 cell G2, then the following code will add the formula to all the cells in Column G, after counting how many rows there are in Column A:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet3")
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'get the last row with data on Column A
    ws.Range("G2:G" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Sheet1!RC[-5]=""low"",1,IF(Sheet1!RC[-5]=""medium"",2,IF(Sheet1!RC[-5]=""high"",3,IF(Sheet1!RC[-5]=""extreme"",4))))"
    'above enter the formula
    ws.Range("G2:G" & LastRow).Value = ws.Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Value
    'convert the formula to its value
End Sub
```